# How to make redux-form (or Redux in general) work nice with a local database?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

It's days or maybe weeks (reading articles, watching videos/talks) that I'm trying to understand how to use Redux and [redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form) correctly but it's really hard for me to fully grasp the concept. Maybe my usecase is not well suited for Redux or maybe I'm simply missing something obvious.

What I'm trying to find is a good foundation for a large application. I'm fairly convinced about React, but Redux (and in consequence, redux-form) seems like a good solution for a problem that I'm not having. Still, everybody praises the Redux (or flux) concept, so I want to make sure that I'm not missing something.

Well, the application is heavily **database-driven** with **all data readily available in the browser** (it's a offline-first application).

I'm using a in-browser database *very similar to* [NeDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) plus a [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/)-like ODM, but actually the database is a(nother) custom project that I want to open-source once it is stable enough (I *do have* implemented it already and it works very good so far).

> The key points of that database (relevant to this question) are probably that it has *all* data readily available in the browser and that it supports "**live queries**" - that means that I can **subscribe** to database changes and up-to-date query results are pushed directly to any consuming component/handler. Furthermore, the database automatically **synchronizes all data with a server** in background (two-way), meaning that collections may change contents in any moment.

As UI frontend I'm using **[Material UI](http://www.material-ui.com/)**.

The application itself will manage quite a number of different collections and I need to implement a number of forms for the user so that he can edit single documents in certain collections. Depending on the context in the application the user will see a list of all documents in the current collection and alongside a form showing the details of the currently selected document in that list. That form will of course also allow changes of the document. The user will probably only edit (see) one collection/form at a time.

See this quick [Mockup](https://moqups.com/) for easier understanding:
[image: UI sketch]

The list on the left is ridiculously easy to do with React and the live queries described above. It's also "reactive" in that it is always in-sync with the database. However, it doesn't currently use Redux at all. I'm not sure if that's bad or not.

When clicking any item in that list, the details should show up in the form on the right.

I like the redux-form (v6) concept, but I can't figure out how to feed the document data to the form. I know there is [`initialValues`](http://redux-form.com/6.0.2/examples/initializeFromState/) but I could not understand how to use it properly.

I guess I need to push the *document* data somehow into Redux so that it is reflected in the form. Do I need to "start" a Redux action to push the data into the store?

On the other hand, using classic React *state* to pass the document (a simple JS object) from the list to my form component seems radically simple to me. *At the moment* I don't see any benefit from having a global form state in the Redux store. But then, I probably need something else than redux-form (couldn't find anything comparable).

Redux with my database seems also redundant to me since in the end both are global data stores.

I *do* use Redux already for a handful states that have nothing to do with database *contents*, like application status indicators and to toggle a global [drawer](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/drawer). I'm also using [redux-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-router) (and **ultimately would like to link the current list selection an unique URI**). Yet I'm having a hard time to find a harmonic link between Redux and the database/database-related components.

So, my question in the end is: What's a reasonable way to implement these parts of the application? Redux or not Redux? In either case: how can it implemented?

Answer (score 0):

If all your data is available more or less synchronously locally, Redux might not be that great a fit for your application.

However, if you want to use Redux Form, which provides a lot of form state management out of the box, you will need to use Redux, even if you only use it for the Redux Form reducer.

To initialize your form, you can either pass the values in via an `initialValues` prop to the decorated form component, or you may also call `dispatch(initialize(formName, formValues))` yourself.

Comment: What to say... I did try `initialValues` before but failed. I guess I "failed to see the wood for the trees" after too much learning and did some stupid mistakes. Anyway, I tried again and it works like a charm. Awesome! :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following package I've written:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-offline-wizard

the base idea is to:
1) save redux to browser storage and rehydrate (reload from storage to redux store)
2) add a new branch to redux store to implement an outgoing queue for requests. any async XHR action will add a request to queue. Queue requests will be sent when user is online or comes back online and will be retried if failed because of network conditions